# Codedeploy with S3 always fails after 5 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I've spent the better half of the day trying to setup CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, S3 and EC2.

Codepipeline will successfully:

- Pick up detected changes in GitHub
- Push the ZIP file up to S3
- Trigger CodeDeploy to begin deployment

Also

1. **EC2** has list and read access to S3
2. S3 allows all actions from **EC2**

I've followed this outdated guide mostly: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-deploy-application-code-from-s3-using-aws-codedeploy/

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www

hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: hooks/after-install.sh
      runas: root
```

I'm rather new to AWS and can't *for my life* find where the logs are telling me what's going on, nor do I get any error message that points me anywhere, so I've literally been shooting blind double checking everything all day and trying again and this is taunting me now:

[image]
[image]

Any help even if it's pointing me towards where I can actually find the error message would be tremendously appreciated, thanks for your time

Comment: Have you go the code deploy agent running on the EC2 instance? And can you confirm the instance can speak outbound to the internet?

Comment: No and no, wow.. thank you will give that a whirl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally occurs for one of the following 3 reasons:

- The CodeDeploy agent needs to be [installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html) and running on the target instance.
- No access to CodeDeploy and S3 service. Either ensure you are:

  - Running an instance in a public subnet with an internet gateway
  - Running an instance in a private subnet with a NAT gateway/NAT instance
- The IAM permissions for the IAM role of the instance are not sufficient, for sufficient permissions attach the `AWSCodeDeployRole` policy.

As you have said your IAM role permissions are fine you are left with one of the other 2 scenarios.

Once these are working you can generally see the logs within the `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent` location.